# Passing arguments between

Tags: python, csv, command, arguments

I have hundreds of malware files, and analyzing them using IDAPython. I managed to automate the disassembly operation, but I also want to extract some statistics and features from the disassembled file, and store the results in a CSV file. I have two python files. 1st one for automating IDA Pro by calling

```
rc = os.system("\"C:\IDAPro6.6\idaw64.exe\" -A -OIDAPython:countV3.py %s %s" % (pida_path, dir + '\\' + file))
```

While the 2nd file (countV3.py) extracts the required statistics i.e. number of functions, instructions, segments,etc, and stores the results in a CSV file. By I don't know how to pass the file name (the last argument in the os.system command) to the 2nd python file in order to record it in my CSV file.

Here there how I iterate over the files:

```
dir = sys.argv[1]
files = os.listdir(dir)
for file in files:
  if not file.endswith("asm"):
    continue
  pida_path = dir + '\\' + file.split('.')[0] + ".asm"
  print "[*] Grabbing pida from %s" % (dir + "\\" + file)
  rc = os.system("C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe" -A -OIDAPython:countV3.py %s %s" % (pida_path, dir + '\\' + file))
```

Comment: By "how to pass the file name to the 2nd python file" if you literally want to pass the file name to the python file, can't you use `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: I received an error states that index out of range, it parses countV3.py as sys.argv[1] and anything beyond this index is considered out of range

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the [dir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) command here --> `(pida_path, dir + '\\' + file)`, perhaps you want to use `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: I've checked also the number of arguments through len(sys.argv), and the output is one. This means it recognized only one argument. 
I'm new to python, so I'm not quite sure if I need dir or os.getcwd() can be used instead.

Comment: Before calling `os.system()`, I'd recommend building the full string and making sure it looks correct first. Also, why the extra backslash `"\"` at the beginning "\"C:\? You might want to remove that. And maybe consider changing the name of `file` variable, [file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a keyword in python]. `dir` is also a keyword, and probably doesn't do what you want it to do here, see [dir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: I did that, and received following error 
[*] Grabbing pida from c:\dataset\ff85e3a32e06ba6011034e68bf40ccbc.asm
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[*] Grabbing pida from c:\dataset\ffcb81e53263f5aacb1e98687bbad772.asm
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[*] Grabbing pida from c:\dataset\ffce18fd9d0b4d69240cae73346bc9d8.asm
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[*] Grabbing pida from c:\dataset\ffdddb4adb35989cfd055898f7a4b669.asm
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Try adding double backslashes to the first part like this `os.system("C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe"`, and leave the rest the same

Comment: Thanks for your assistance
This is how I iterate over the files
`dir = sys.argv[1]

files = os.listdir(dir)
 
for file in files:
    if not file.endswith("asm"):
        continue
     
    pida_path = dir + '\\' + file.split('.')[0] + ".asm"
    print "[*] Grabbing pida from %s" % (dir + "\\" + file)
    rc = os.system("C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe" -A -OIDAPython:countV3.py %s %s" % (pida_path, dir + '\\' + file))`

Comment: received an error for double backslash :(
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what is the output for `print os.path.exists("C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe")`?

Comment: For that long argument you are passing to `os.system()` I'd recommend formatting it using the [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) syntax so it will be clearer to understand

Comment: the output is true

Comment: If the output is `True`, then the double backslashes should be working

Comment: Thanks a lot
By the error is syntax error, which isn't related to the existence of the directory

Comment: try this: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/3ILp9Fj6rekM9ysr6eQa/

Comment: Tried it, but receiving this error
`[*] Grabbing pida from C:\Dataset\ffe085e225205bfe30521a46d69f7b6a.asm
['C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe', '-A', '-OIDAPython:countV3.py', 'C:\\Dataset\\ffe0
85e225205bfe30521a46d69f7b6a.asm']
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[*] Grabbing pida from C:\Dataset\fff49ba8407d329fffc4a6f39737efcc.asm
['C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe', '-A', '-OIDAPython:countV3.py', 'C:\\Dataset\\fff4
9ba8407d329fffc4a6f39737efcc.asm']
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Hmm..well, can you make the command manually in `cmd.exe`, without using the python script, that works? What would it look like? Does `C:\\IDAPro6.6\\idaw64.exe -A -OIDAPython:countV3.py ffe085e225205bfe30521a46d69f7b6a.asm` work?

Comment: The problem I have a big dataset about 1100 files. So, I need to record the file name alongside its information throughout the 2nd python file

Comment: That's why I think we should test only one command in windows `cmd.exe` before we script it in python or use it in `os.system`. can you test *only one* file on the windows `cmd.exe` command line and get the correct output? if not, then scripting it in python isn't going to work yet..

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your assistance. 
Yes, single command from cmd works.

Comment: Ok that's good one command works, I don't know why it's not working in the python script. If one command works with `cmd.exe`, then that same command should work for all files in python like this https://paste.pound-python.org/show/LwyCJ1GzAwOYUJ2woddz/